# Two Form Actions In One Form PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have two problems with my php code.

First one is how variable

```
$linkorig
```

can see after

```
$_POST['formsubmitted']
```

,when i get it from redirected page?

Second question is how can do form submit with different action, after all error checking ?

Maybe possible with some javascript or php code.

```
<?php
    $linkorig=$_POST['link-orig']; // get destination link from redirected page , for excample http://mikrotik.lv -- works fine 
    if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) 
    {
        // script try login with credentials  with  <form action="login.php"   --- works fine
        //Error checking !
        if (empty($error)) //if not found any errors {
            // login with credentials and same form but  with  <form action="other_login.php"   --- i dont know how to do :(
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login"  action="login.php"  method="post" class="registration_form" onSubmit="return doLogin()" >
            <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="<?php echo $linkorig; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login Form  </legend>
                <p>Enter Your username and Password Below  </p>
                <div class="elements">
                    <label for="name">Email :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="username" size="25" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" size="25" />
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" value="OK" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <!-- $(if error) -->
            <br /><div style="color: #FF8080; font-size: 9px"> </div>
        <!-- $(endif) -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            document.login.username.focus();
            //-->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "in this site i cant normaly insert code" — You might want to try reading the *How to Format* box that appears next to the question input then.

Comment: You can either do the posts as Xhr posts with JavaScript or use `curl` to essentially 'forward' the received post on from the server upon first receipt.  That last option is how you can get around some 'same origin' issues as well.

Comment: or do a google search for "post get redirect"

Comment: I suggest you to post 2 different (and specific) questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use one form for 2 actions :

```
<form method='post' action='post.php'>
<input type='text' name='field1' />
<input type='text' name='field1' />

<button name='action1'>action1</button>
<button name='action2'>action2</button>
</form>
```

On the page `post.php` :

All your variable will be in `$_POST`, namely `$_POST['field1'], $_POST['field2'], $_POST['action1'] and $_POST['action2']`
Use a simple condition :

```
if(isset($_POST['action1'])) {
  //some code here but still check action2

  // edit : you can call the action2 with jquery and [ajax][1]
  // you can use header('location: http://example.com?field1='.$_POST['field1'].'&field2='.$_POST['field1']) to redirect, but no output before using header => see ob_get_clean() if you have any problem.
}
else { exit; } //stop it all if action1 failed
```

---

However, if you redirect your page, you have no longer $_POST variable. You can use `/page.php?var1=...` and $_GET them the same as you would do with $_POST.

Comment: Or he could just include('other_form.php') in the conditional, or write a class and do the form processing there, or anything else that makes sense where as desiring a separate action as described in the question is programatically asinine. I think the brunt of this problem is that he doesn't really grasp the concept of form processing and flow of site. There's no reason to not do the processing right here and then relocate header afterward.

Comment: Hmm..realy nice....! But  can it done with if action1 fails then everything stops, but if action 1 passed , then  do action 2

Comment: NVM, they are buttons instead of type submit, my bad.